# A program that will return the cell address of the minimum value in a row?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

So I have a chart that looks something like this. Assume that the top left value, 1, is in cell A1:

```
x=    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8

      4    3    2    1    2    3    4    5

      9    8    7    6    7    8    9    10

      8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1

Sum= 21   18   15   12   13   14   15    16
```

There are x values from 1 to 8, and a three columns of values resulting from using it an equation or something below it. The sum is the sum of the three values below their corresponding x-value.

I'm stuck trying to figure something out that will go through the row of sums, find the smallest value, and then assign it's corresponding x-value to a variable. I also need to assign the values to the left and right of that x-value to other variables.

For this particular chart, 12 is the smallest of the sums, so I would assign `variable1 = 4`, since that is that column's corresponding x-value. Then my second variable, which is called `lowerbound`, would equal 3, since it is to the left of x = 4, and my third variable, which is called `upperbound`, would equal 5, since it is to the right of x = 4.

If I could get the cell address returned of the x-value that corresponds to the smallest sum, then I could assign it to a variable, and then simply offset from that cell to assign the other variables. Even if I could make a program that will return me the cell of the minimum sum value, I could offset to the x-row, and go from there.

How would I do something like that?

**TL:DR: To ask more clearly, since that's a lot of words: What would a program look like that detects the smallest value in the sum row, and returns the cell address of that value?**

The length of the rows are an unknown, and vary a lot, but the length of the columns are given. They do change depending on the problem, but they will always be known. So I will always know how many rows are in a column, but I will not know how many columns are in a row.

This is the most confusingly-worded thing I've ever written in my entire life, but I hope I've explained it well enough to make some sense.

You guys really are amazing, by the way. I've gotten so far on this program, and it's all because of how helpful you are. I honestly think I would still be stuck at the beginning with you guys! You're willing to tolerate a newbie's incessant questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming that the sum is in `A4:H4`. Please change as applicable

You can use a formula like

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A4:H4,MATCH(MIN(A4:H4),A4:H4,0)))
```

If you want to use VBA then you can use this

```
Sub Sample()
    MsgBox Application.Evaluate("=CELL(""address"",INDEX(A4:H4,MATCH(MIN(A4:H4),A4:H4,0)))")
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly does Match() do? And thank you for your help!

Edit: Also is there a way to do this that doesn't involve knowing the length of the row?

Comment: The MATCH function searches for a specified item in a range (range: Two or more cells on a sheet. The cells in a range can be adjacent or nonadjacent.) of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range. I would recommend checking the Excel's inbuilt Help. for `CELL`, `INDEX`, `MATCH` etc...

Comment: Ha, you posted this as I was writing my answer. I'm out of votes for today, will upvote you later.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve knowing the length of the row?

Comment: yes. try this :) `=CELL("address",INDEX(4:4,MATCH(MIN(4:4),4:4,0)))` or in VBA `Application.Evaluate("=CELL(""address"",INDEX(4:4,MATCH(MIN(4:4),4:4,0)))")`

Comment: My main issue right now is I'm not too sure how to make this information usable? I can use this to give me the address of the cell in the form of $A$5, but I'm not sure how to set this value to a variable, or something, and actually use it? I keep getting a data type mismatch. My goal is to offset from the cell address in row 1 whose value in row 5 is the lowest, but I'm not sure how. For example, how would I get this program to offset from the cell in question to the left one, and set that cell to a variable, and then offset from the cell in question to the right one, and set that to one too?

Comment: Do you mean get the value of the cell on the left and right of the lowest value?

Comment: No, to get the value of the cells to the left and right of the x-value.

Comment: x? Can you give me an example using the sample data that you posted?

Comment: Okay! So the program detects which column has the smallest value in row five. It then assigns the value for x in that column to a variable. The x-values are in row 1. They are not a part of what is summed. Rows 2, 3, and 4 are results from x being used in an equation. The program then assigns the x-value to the left and right of this to their own variables. So for this example, Xmin = 4, XLeft = 3, XRight = 5. I need to use VBA because depending on user input, the amount of rows and columns will change, along with the data in them.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes this can be achieved. Will the X values always remain in Row 1?

Comment: Yes they will always be in Row 1.

Comment: I see you have posted a new question for this? Do you want me to paste the code therE?

Answer (score 7):

Using your example, the following formula returns the cell address in row 1 whose value in row 5 is the lowest:

`=ADDRESS(1,MATCH(MIN(A5:H5),A5:H5,0))`

And if you want that cell's value, use `INDIRECT`. It takes the address as a string.

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(MIN(A5:H5),A5:H5,0)))`

Comment: `Ha, you posted this as I was writing my answer. I'm out of votes for today, will upvote you later. – JimmyPena 1 min ago`+ 1 Sorry LOL :)

Comment: So, first of all, I'm using Excel VBA to do this. Would I just use `Application.Evaluate("=Cell(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(MIN(A5:H5),A5:H5,0)))` to do so? My main issue right now is I'm not too sure how to make this information usable? I can get the top one to give me the address of the cell in the form of $A$5,a nd I can get the indirect one to give me the value in the cell, but I'm not sure how to set these values to variables and actually use them? I keep getting a data type mismatch. My goal is to offset from the cell address in row 1 whose value in row 5 is the lowest, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: [Siddharth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11638839/190829) shows you how to use the Evaluate function to return the value of a worksheet function in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

If you sum the columns by taking the sum of the array. Here is the VBA version:

```
For j = 1 To 8
     For i = 1 To 3
          sum(j) = sum(j) + Cells(i + 1, j + 1)
    Next i
    Cells(5, j + 1) = sum(j)
Next j
```